# Програмувати на Джаві, чи програмувати Джавою?

Tags: терміни, правопис, запозичені-слова

Чи поширюється правила і норми української мови, за якими ми "говоримо італійською", а не "говоримо по-італійськи" чи "на італійській", на мови програмування?

Як правильно "Я програмую на Python'і" чи "Я програмую Python'ом"? А як що до "Я пишу на Python", чи "Я пишу Python'ом? 
І як бути з такими мовами, назви яких невідмінювані як-от PHP (пі-ейч-пі), Ruby(рубі) чи С(сі)?

Comment: Ну, з людськими мовами не все так однозначно — насправді [правильних варіантів багато](/a/3433/4) — і той, хто каже, що можна тільки по-одному, лише збіднює нашу мову. Але «програмую Пітоном» я ніколи не чув (хоча це було б логічно; можливо, те, що назви багатьох мов невідмінювані й при спробі поставити їх в орудний відмінок буде незрозуміло, що це орудний відмінок, уплинуло на вживаність).

Comment: Люди, зазвичай, говорять "на". Можливо, це неправильно, але я не знаходив спростування.

Comment: "поставити їх в орудний відмінок буде незрозуміло, що це орудний відмінок, уплинуло на вживаність)" - скоріше спаклюжило, зіпсувало, пошкодило, позбавило гнукості. Позбавило розуміння мови.

Answer (score 1):

Українською мовою ми **спілкуємось** і **розуміємось**, а програмуємо (тобто пишемо програмний код) лише **на Пайтон**, **на Джава** або **на Сі**, так само не **говоримо** мертвими мовами, наприклад **на санскриті**.

**Мова програмування** — це система позначень для опису алгоритмів та структур даних, створена для передачі команд машинам, зокрема комп'ютерам.

**Літературна мова** зазвичай походить від *національної та реалізується в усній і писемній формах. Літературна мова обслуговує безпосереднє спілкування людей, побутові й виробничі потреби та функціонує у сфері державної, політичної, господарської, наукової та культурної діяльності.

На відміну від [штучної комп'ютерної](https://wiki.cuspu.edu.ua/index.php/%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) мови, важливою ознакою літературної мови є Алфавіт, словотворення та складення речень. Отже мови програмування лише переймають ознаку "мова", на зразок людьських мов, але не є мовами в загальновживаному розумінні. Таким чином їхні назви необхідно перекладати за загальними правилами, а саме як для [незмінюваних іменників](http://shkolyar.in.ua/pravopys-imennykiv/pravopys-inozemnyh) (власних назв) іншомовного походження в [орудному відмінку](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/kljasichnij_pravopis/zakinchennja_vidminjuvanikh_sliv/orudnij_vidminok_odnina/62-1-0-15551) однини:

1. Рід власних назв визначають на основі відповідної загальної назви, наприклад: місто, озеро, річка, країна, острів, мова.
2. Власні назви зберігають рід загальних назв. Тобто, якщо вживати окремо без загального слова "Пайтон" або "Сі", вони матимуть ознаки жіночого роду однини.
3. Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються. Не відмінюємо іменники іншомовного походження у власних і непослідовно в загальних назвах з наголошеним **а**, а також непослідовно у власних назвах з ненаголошеним:

**а**: амплуа́, боа́, мас-ме́дія, Брази́лія (столиця Бразилії), Нікара́гуа; бра, па; антраша́, бакара́, Доза́, Дюма́, Сая́т-Нова́; Вітто́ріо де Си́ка (але, наприклад, прізвища Казано́ва, Куроса́ва відмінюємо);
**е**: кафе́, кашне́, турне́, Туапсе́, Беранже́, Ґе́те;
**є**: ательє́, конферансьє́, Барб’є́, Ґотьє́, Лавуазьє́;
**и** (крім випадків, коли ця буква означає форму множини іменників: Єсентуки́ і т. ин.): Алмати́, Аман-гельди́, Мари́;
**і**: колі́брі, по́ні, таксі́, цуна́мі, Гаї́ті, Дебюссі́, Ше́ллі;
**ї**: Віньї́, Луї́;
**о** (коли перед ним стоїть инший голосний): ра́діо, Онта́ріо, Бази́ліо, Ма́ріо, але пальто́ — пальта́, пальто́м, (у) пальті́; так само б’юро́, депо́, кіно́, метро́, ситро́;
**у**: какаду́, у́рду, шо́у, Баку́, Папандре́у, Попе́ску;
**ю**: інтерв’ю́, меню́, К’юсю́, Сю;
**я** (в позиції під наголосом або в односкладових словах): Золя́.

Примітка!
утворюють групу назв — незмінюваних імен альді, аймара, бенгалі, навахо, банту, пушту, урду, гінді, фіджі, гуджарані, комі, саамі, ідиш, бхілі, ідо, есперанто тощо. Однотипна характеристика середнього роду не властива цим назвам. Іменники урду, гінді, альді, аймара, бенгалі, бхілі та ін. зазнали трансформації родової залежності відповідно до родової ознаки тематичного слова, напр.: «Альді (штучна міжнародна мова) складається з 2500 слів, переважно коротких і однозначних» (журн.); «У самій Індії одні вважають, що гінді й урду — дві різні мови, інші вважають їх двома стилями однієї й тієї ж мови» (журн.); «Шолом-Алейхем починав свій творчий труд на мові іврит» (з газ.); «...мов промовля на мові есперанто пелюстка кожна в тирлича жива» (Є. Гуцало).

Таким чином: **програмувати мовою Джава 
або програмувати на Джаві, але не Джавою.**

Comment: Хоча… Я подумав… Але ж говорять/пишуть [латиною](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac5&queryselector=wordrow&word=латиною). І [пишуть санскритом](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac5&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22.*пи[сш].*%22+%22санскритом%22). Тож, мабуть, щось не те.

Comment: Так, вірно, нехай вас не лякає мертва мова, латиною пишуть і говорять, але на санскриті лише пишуть. 
"Санскрит уже в середині І тисячоліття до н. е. не був розмовною мовою, але традиція розмовляти на санскриті ніколи не переривалася." - https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Санскрит

Comment: Можливо, додасте якісь джерела?

Comment: @Sasha StackExchange цікавий саме змістовним обґрунтуванням, притаманним науковому підходу.
Не думаю, що цю відповідь варто вважати відповіддю на питання.

Comment: Алфавіт, словотворення і складання речень є і в Java

Comment: «Важливою ознакою літературної мови є алфавіт, словотворення та складення речень» — однак про мову програмування можна сказати те саме: важливими ознаками мови програмування є [алфавіт](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Формальні_граматики#Поняття_алфавіту), творення [виразів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вираз_(інформатика)) і складання [інструкцій](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Інструкція_(програмування)). Втім, я не заперечую, що «мови програмування лише переймають ознаку „мова“, на зразок людьських мов, але не є мовами в загальновживаному розумінні», просто оте речення про важливі ознаки не доводить цього.

Comment: «Таким чином їхні назви необхідно перекладати за правилами для іменників (власних назв) іншомовного походження в орудному відмінку однини…» — не зрозумів, то Ви кажете, що **треба** в орудному відмінку чи що **не можна** в орудному відмінку? «Рід власних назв визначають на основі відповідної загальної назви», «власні назви зберігають рід загальних назв» — не зрозумів звідки ці правила. **І вони не відповідають дійсності: _рідне місто_, але _рідний Київ_ (а не _рідне Київ_).**

Comment: По-перше, Київ не є словом іншомовного походження.
По-друге, власні назви набувають ознаки роду від загального назви (іменника).

Comment: Таким чином,
 рідний Києве - вірно,
 рідний Київ - не вірно.

Comment: @RomanMikhol, не дуже розумію як саме ваша відповідь пояснює наявність прийменника "на". Поясніть будь ласка. Також, чи не могли би ви прокоментувати ось такий приклад: "Я літаю RyanAir-ом"? Цей приклад має підпадати під ваше пояснення, але все ж таки ми не кажемо "Я літаю на RyanAir-і". Дякую.

Comment: @Oleksandr,
За правилами [нової редакції](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/osnovni-zminy%202019.pdf) «УКРАЇНСЬКОГО ПРАВОПИСУ» (2019) назви товарних знаків, марок виробів треба писати в лапках з великої літери або з малої букви, якщо вживається як загальна назва.

Ryanair - [офіційно зареєстрована в Україні торгівельна марка](http://base.uipv.org/searchBul/search.php?action=viewdetails&dbname=tmc&IdClaim=434133), може бути відтворена українською лише як «Райанейр», якщо йдеться саме про назву або «райанейр», якщо використовувати в загальному вжитку.

Comment: Дякую за відповіді, але я все ж таки не зрозумів як правильно. Буду вдячний, якщо хтось наведе прості приклади з поясненнями.

Comment: Переклад назв штучних мов правилами Українського Правопису не врегульовано. Тобто перекладаємо за Загальними правилами Українського Правопису для слів іншомовного походження: "Код цієї програми написаний на [мові програмування] Пайтон, на Джава, на Ангулар". Але, якщо ви є носієм однієї або декількох **високорівневих штучних мов**, то відповідно можете і програмувати **пайтоном**, **рубі** чи **хаскелем**.